# proxy option with in my app

Tags: c#, proxy

I wrote a small app that downloads YouTube videos but like most company's they don't allow you to view YouTube so i would like to incorporate a proxy option into my app to download the YouTube videos through a supplied proxy ip and port.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Exactly what should this proxy do?

Comment: on the menu tab ill have options and then proxy under that when you click on proxy form pops up and you edit your proxy settings once done you hit save and then you can paste in your  youtube link and it will download the video through the proxy you set up in under porxy settings.

Comment: Are you sure you need an app for that? Why don't you just use IE or Firefox, and change your proxy settings in there?

Comment: I would like to learn how to implement proxy settings into my applications, I am a network admin and we have our browser settings locked down so you cant change them. I just would like my app to use a specific proxy.

Comment: to download, can System.Net.WebProxy class be used in this way ?

Comment: @summeylabs - the configuration sample i provided will work with any .NET binary. The settings shown override the machinewide .NET framework proxy settings. You do not need to change any of your application code unless the application itself insists to connect to a proxy. Only in this case you would want to look into WebRequest.Proxy. Just add a Whateveryour.exe.config with the desired proxy settings along your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this [configuration settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e.aspx):

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy>
            <proxy
              usesystemdefault="true"
              proxyaddress="http://192.168.1.10:3128"
              bypassonlocal="true"
            />
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

This way you can reference the system proxy settings or override them with your own.

If your app derives from [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28VS.80%29.aspx) you could look into [WebRequest.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy%28VS.80%29.aspx).

---

**UPDATE**

To make your .NET app use a specific proxy do the following:

**Create** a file named [Your_App_Name].exe.config in the same folder your app resides

**Edit** the newly created file to contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
    <configuration>
        <system.net>
            <defaultProxy>
                <proxy usesystemdefault="False" 
                   proxyaddress="<YOUR_PROXY_IP_ADDRESS>:<YOUR_PROXY_PORT>" 
                   bypassonlocal="True" />
            </defaultProxy>
        </system.net>
    </configuration>
```

**Replace** *<YOUR_PROXY_IP_ADDRESS>* and *<YOUR_PROXY_PORT>* with the proxy you'd like to use.